# How to create global Javascript variable in Scala js?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I need to create global JS variable in my Scala js.
How this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Via Facade Type

Make an object that extends `js.GlobalScope`:

```
object MyGlobal extends js.GlobalScope {
  var globalVar: String
}
```

Then, just assign to it:

```
MyGlobal.globalVar = "foo"
```

### Via Dynamic interface

```
js.Dynamic.global.globalVar = "foo"
```

### Caveat

Both of these methods need code to be *executed* before the variable is set to anything. There is currently no way to directly export a top-level value in Scala.js without executing code (see [#1381](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1381)).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export the `g` shortcut:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.Dynamic.{ global => g }
g.myVar = "foo"
```